# How to create a popup box where users can copy text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

In my HTML page I generate a link, where users can grab to use for things. I need to somehow give the user the link where they can see the link and then copy the link to clip board.

I don't mean copy to clip board through code, just manually selecting the text and clicking `ctrl+c` or `right click+copy` is ok.

Is there a way I can create a popup box where it has text there that you can select and copy?

This needs to work with all browsers (IE8+) (Firefox) (Chrome) (especially **IE8**). So if I use alert box, I will not be able to copy the text so I can't use alerts.

Is there some really easy way that doesn't involve lots of code and also not using another HTML file for the popup box or something.

I can even use jquery if that makes it easy. Really, just a way to show a popup where the user can copy the text, and this is all done with code.

Thanks.

Comment: You can copy the text displayed with `alert` with `ctrl+c`

Comment: I tried it, but I need it to be an easy windows experience as the users are not techies, and they would think that the text would need to be highlighted first which wont work. Plus I need it to select exactly the link, when i tried it with an alert box, it shows some other stuff they you would normally see on a log file.

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery ui [`.dialog()`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try and use window.prompt() and do something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt where you can copy the text from the input, which can default to the link.

Comment: This is neat, but are you able to hide the ok button? Im not sure but the ok and cancel might confuse users, like they might think they need to do something. If not, then I might just go with a jquery dialog.

Answer (score 1):

with jquery you can do something like this

```
$(function() {
    $( "<div>Your text here </div>" ).dialog();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd user a overlaying div, which would appear on a click event. It would contain the text You would like to be able to copy and a close button. (using jQuery!)

First save Your div's content in a string variable. Let us call this variable `divCont`.

After this we create the overlaying div:

```
var docHeight = $(document).height();
$("body").append("<div id='overlayDiv'></div>").hide().fadeIn("slow");
$overlayDiv = $("#overlayDiv");
$overlayDiv.height(docHeight).css({
        'opacity' : 0.9,
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': 0,
        'background-color': 'black',
        'width': '100%',
        'z-index': 5000,
        'margin-left': 10%,
        'margin-right': 10%,
        'color': 'white'
});
```

Then we append the content of the $overlayDiv with our divCont string and we add a close button to it:

```
$overlayDiv.append(divCont+"<button id='close'>CLOSE</button>'");
```

After this we add a handler to the close:

```
$("#close").ready(function(){
   $(document).on("click", "#close", function(){
      $overlayDiv.fadeOut("slow", function(){
         $overlayDiv.remove();
      });
   });
});
```

Link to working example -> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puvCe/6/)

Answer (score 0):

create a **fixed** div in the middle of the screen (or where ever you want it to be) with a input text box within it. You can trigger this structure whenever you generate a link.

[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puvCe/)

```
<div id = "clipboard">
   <input type = "text"></input>
</div>
```

CSS style would be

```
#clipboard{
position: fixed;
left: 40%;
top: 40%;
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
border: thin solid grey;

}

#clipboard input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use an iframe

```
    --------opener.html

<html>
<head>
<title>modalopener</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

var modalWin = null;

function openModal() {
if (window.showModalDialog) {
modalWin = window.showModalDialog('modalchild.html',null,'dialogWidth=300px;        dialogHeight=200px;  status=0');
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:openModal()"><b>open modal window</b></a>
</body>
</html>

--------modalchild.html

<html>
<head>
<title>Modal Child</title>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0">
<iframe name="modalChild" width="100%" height="100%" src="modaliframe.html" frameborder="0">        </iframe>
</body>
</html>

--------modaliframe.html

<html>
<head>
<title>Modal Iframe</title>
</head>
<body leftmargin=0 topmargin=0 bgcolor="pink">
<div align="center"><br>
<a href="#" onclick="loadIFrm('http://www.yahoo.com')">yahoo</a><br>
<a href="#" onclick="loadIFrm('http://www.google.com')">google</a><br>
<a href="#" onclick="loadIFrm('http://www.hotbot.com')">hotbot</a>
</div>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
// call this to reload
function loadIFrm(url) {
location = url;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```